# Использование Sorted со своей функцией (key=func)

Tags: python, сортировка

Почему функция **swap** не меняет местами элементы в каждом принимаемом кортеже?

```
x = [(1, 'pram'), (3, 'dorie'), (1, 'kayak'), (3, 'canoe')]


def swap(t):
    return t[1], t[0]


print(sorted(x, key=swap))
```

Comment: Потому что сортировка сортирует элементы, а не изменяет их

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если верить справке:

```
>>> help(sorted)
```

> Help on built-in function sorted in module builtins:
>
> sorted(...)
>
> sorted(iterable, key=None, reverse=False) --> **new sorted list**

Данная операция возвращает новый отсортированный список, не меняя оригинала. Для изменения существующего списка нужно использовать `x.sort(key=swap)`

Comment: Спасибо. Функция **swap** возвращает переставленные элементы и программа сортирует список по строкам в кортежах. А структура кортежей не меняется. Правильно?

Comment: `swap` задает правило сортировки, `sorted` и `sort` непосредственно сортируют. Но `sorted` создает на выходе новый массив кортежей, отсортированных по правилу `swap`, а `sort` меняет структуру исходного кортежа, не создавая нового.

Comment: т.е. при `sorted` кортеж не меняется, а создается новый, но уже отсортированный

Answer (score 2):

key определяет как следует элементы списка сравнивать:

```
>>> sorted([(1, 'b'), (2, 'a')])
[(1, 'b'), (2, 'a')]
>>> sorted([(1, 'b'), (2, 'a')], key=lambda t: (t[1], t[0]))
[(2, 'a'), (1, 'b')]
```

В первом случае сперва числа сравниваются, во втором — буквы.

key не предназначен, чтобы сами элементы изменять, поэтому неверно передавать swap функцию (имя намекает, что вы хотите чтобы эта функция  переставляла значения внутри кортежа).

`sorted()` возвращает список с возможно переставленными элементами (кортежами). `sorted()` не изменяет сами элементы (кортеж в любом случае неизменяем).

Чтобы переставить значения внутри кортежа необходимо новый создать:

```
>>> [(x[1], x[0]) for x in [(1,'b'), (2, 'a')]]
[('b', 1), ('a', 2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Как правильно написал @andreymal, потому что сортировка сортирует элементы, а не изменяет их. Для изменения элементов служит функция [map](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#map)

```
print(list(map(swap, x)))
```

Или можно воспользоваться [списковым включением](https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
print([(t[1], t[0]) for t in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте использовать функцию `map()`, она позволяет применить какую-либо функцию ко всем элементам массива:

```
x = [(1, 'pram'), (3, 'dorie'), (1, 'kayak'), (3, 'canoe')]


def swap(t):
    return t[1], t[0]


print(list(map(swap, x)))
```